# Start an application after build in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, build

I want to start an application after I built my solution in visual studio.
I'm running a batch file on the postbuild event, but I can't start the application, it opens an empty console.

Answer (score 0):

If the application you are starting from you batch files forces the batch to wait till the application completes running it will cause the application you are building to never complete building.

Basically your build task does not complete so the build does not complete.